# How should I format my cell to have a bulleted list of items

Tags: excel

How should I format my cell to have a bulleted list of items. Currently I create the bulleted text in word and paste it in the excel cell, but when I try to add a new item using the enter button it takes me to the next cell but doesn't add a new bullet item. How should I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mike Alexander had a [post](https://web.archive.org/web/20171224224056/http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/using-bullet-points-in-excel) about this last year. His method uses custom "number" formatting on the cells.

- Paste in your bullet (he chooses one by using Insert->Symbol)
- copy the symbol to the clipboard
- format the range/column needing the bullets and use bullet + <kbd>Space</kbd> + `@` as the formatter.

Note that this only works on items in individual cells (it will only put a single bullet at the beginning of the cell.) If you need to add bullets into a single cell, Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to add a new line character, and copy 'n' paste your bullet character.

Comment: Would be nice to use conditional formatting and only apply the bullet format when some condition on other cell(s) in row is TRUE. Probably can be done -- I just have to go play with Excel conditional formatting again.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to dedicate a column for the bullets, say column A for the bullet and column B for the data, and make the bullet appear conditionally on available data in B. e.g. for cell A1 I would use something like:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B1),"","●")
```

You can then make column A narrow so it will fit in width to the bullet. Also you can copy this formula to a far off row so that any time you write in column B, you'll already have this formula ready in the cell next to it in column A.

Also, if you want to change the bullet's style - go to any empty cell, click on Inset\Symbol, choose your bullet, then you can copy paste it into the equation above.

Answer (score 0):

## *Shortcuts:*

> To quickly add a bullet symbol to a cell, double click in the cell where you want to add your bullet symbol, and then press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> using the numeric keypad on your keyboard.
>
> Ref: [Insert bullets in a worksheet](https://web.archive.org/web/20150110221719/http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/insert-bullets-in-a-worksheet-HP001174202.aspx)

Comment: the link has been dead. [Here's an updated link for newer office versions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-bullets-in-a-worksheet-60274daa-8079-4b40-8f69-0652dbadb4ec)